# How can I debug a class code?

Tags: 8, debugging

I would like to print out the result of this method and check out what the input is.

```
  public function handleAutocomplete(Request $request, $target_type, $selection_handler, $selection_settings_key) {
    $matches = array();
    // Get the typed string from the URL, if it exists.
    if ($input = $request->query->get('q')) {
      $typed_string = Tags::explode($input);
      $typed_string = Unicode::strtolower(array_pop($typed_string));

      // Selection settings are passed in as a hashed key of a serialized array
      // stored in the key/value store.
      $selection_settings = $this->keyValue->get($selection_settings_key, FALSE);
      if ($selection_settings !== FALSE) {
        $selection_settings_hash = Crypt::hmacBase64(serialize($selection_settings) . $target_type . $selection_handler, Settings::getHashSalt());
        if ($selection_settings_hash !== $selection_settings_key) {
          // Disallow access when the selection settings hash does not match the
          // passed-in key.
          throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('Invalid selection settings key.');
        }
      }
      else {
        // Disallow access when the selection settings key is not found in the
        // key/value store.
        throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();
      }

      $matches = $this->matcher->getMatches($target_type, $selection_handler, $selection_settings, $typed_string);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($matches);
  }

}
```

It is quite difficult to print it out because it's deep in the code. And in a form, when you post, the page is loaded 2 times.

Generally, `print_r()` or `var_dump()` is enough for me to debug, but in this case, I can't just simply use them, so debugging this code is a bit challenging.

Is there any helper class/function I can use to trace/inspect the code?

Comment: Did you try this? https://drupalize.me/blog/201510/how-log-messages-drupal-8

Comment: You can debug this like anything else, print_r/var_dump() works, you just have to actually do an autocomplete suggestion request and then check the network output as it will break the json expection. or use debug() and then refresh the page. Or use an IDE/editor with xdebug support for "real debugging".